# ASP.NET How to create a form which opens on button click floating over current page and fading out BG

Tags: asp.net

Hey As the title suggests I see a lot of forms done in ASP.NET lately which seem to open over the current .net page, fading out the background. Validation of the forms is done on the floater form and if all good and submit is clicked the forms goes back to main page etc..

Just wondering what tools are used to do this, and if anybody has done this and could provide some sample codes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at [Jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/). There is a [Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) (follow the link, then click "Create New User", this is the modal input form with blanked out background) which achieves what you are after. There are good examples on the website too.